# How to model objects that have configuration settings

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm building a Laravel app using a Mysql database, in which users can browse through a list of available tools. The tools are all located at the URL `/tools/{tool-slug}`.

This URL routes to a method in my `ToolController`, which uses the slug to look up the tool in the database and return the appropriate views, js files, and information about the tool back to the browser.

Here's the part where I am looking for some advice:

Each of these tools can have some configuration settings associated to them, and these settings, along with the options for each setting, needs to be viewable on that tools page so the user can adjust the settings as needed.  The available settings are different for each tool.

So, for example, ToolA might have the following configuration options:

```
Page Position -> top, left, bottom
Header Color -> blue, yellow, green
```

And ToolB might have the following settings:

```
Font Weight -> bold, regular
Page Position -> top, left, bottom, right
Header Text -> "Heading 1", "Heading 2", "Heading 3"
```

I'm trying to determine the best way to set up models and tables to represent this information. Here's what I've come up with so far, but I would love to know if anyone has a better idea:

```
ToolConfigOption
 - id
 - tool_id
 - name (this would be things like "Page Position", "Header Text", etc)

ToolConfigOptionValues
 - id
 - tool_config_option_id
 - value (this is the possible values for the option like "top", "bold", etc)

ToolConfig (this assigns the configuration to a specific user)
 - tool_id
 - user_id
 - tool_config_option_id
 - tool_config_option_value_id
```

Now, to list the configuration options for a given tool on that tool's page, I would lookup all the ToolConfigOptions and ToolConfigOptionValues for the given tool. To get the current settings for the tool for the given user, I would look up all the ToolConfig entries for the given user and the given tool.

Comment: Looks good to me :) Do you need any help with the implementation or do you just wanna know if this is the right way to do it?

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to confirm the approach before I started implementing it. I'm sure I will have some more questions once I start.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
User - User Model
Tool - ToolModel
ToolConfig - represents the Tool Configuration options available for each tool
ToolConfigUser - Represents the relationship between Users and Tool Configurations
```